# Where are my hats?

Tags: support, winterbash

I have hats, I'm sure of it, I remember having them last year (or the year before?)
I'm now seeing other people with hats, but Ender is sadly still hatless. How do I get my hats back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Last year's hats have vanished. This year's [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com) is a different event with new hats.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Want your old hats back? You can do this in four easy steps!

`1.` Open up your profile.

[image]

`2.` Hover over your picture and click "Change Picture".

[image]

`3.` Select "Upload a New Picture".

[image]

`4`. Profit!!!

[image]